# What is terminal passwd for fixing stalled Xbuntu installation?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, freeze

I am installing Xbuntu 20.04 and the installer is stuck at about 66% when running update-grub.  This is a known problem and the fix is to switch to a terminal and kill a process associated with os-prober.  However, when I switch to a terminal with ctl-alt-f2 is asks for a username and password.  The one I supplied to the installer doesn't work.  I also tried user ubuntu with no password and xbuntu with no password, and blank user an blank password. Those don't work either.  What to do?

Comment: SO is for programming questions only. OS support is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). Please post on [ubuntu.se] instead.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the username with xubuntu (I had used) xbuntu instead.